# Android click button populate textview

Tags: android

This is week one of Android for me!

I'm programmatically creating a textview, two labels and a button in the same activity. 
The idea is that the textview receives a string from the user. 
The user clicks the button and the textview string is passed to a proc which returns a string result, and the string result is assigned to one of the labels.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
     sresults = showPP(ttsymbol.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

But this doesn't work, because "the final local variable sresults cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

I think I understand what is going wrong, but is there an alternative way of returning the results so that they can be displayed in the label? Or is it necessary to create a new dialog inside the onClick function to show them?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to delete the final keyword from sresult, but this is only an idea. Please, show more detailed code for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure of changing the value of sresults, then there is no point in making it final. `final` is used for constant values.
 You should directly set the value to the label view. The label view reference can be final.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    label.setText(ttsymbol.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More code would be helpful here, how is sresults, showPP, etc defined?  However, the message suggests you have defined sresults as "final" which means you can't change the value.  Probably removing final would solve that problem.